# Calculate the scheme-theoretic closure

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is how to calculate the scheme-theoretic closure by hand. There are two examples I want to calculate.

The first one is III.Example 9.8.4 in Hartshorne. $X_a \subset \mathbb{A}^3\times(\mathbb{A}^1\backslash \{0\})$ is a family of scheme over $\mathbb{A}^1\backslash \{0\}$ defined by

$$\begin{cases} x=t^2-1 \\y=t^3-t\\z=at\end{cases}$$

Then the ideal of scheme-theoretic closure of $X_a$ in $\mathbb{A}^3\times\mathbb{A}^1$ is
$$I=(a^2(x+1)-z^2,ax(x+1)-yz,xz-ay,y^2-x^2(x+1))$$

The second example is EX.III.9.2 in Hartshorne. The question is two find out the scheme-theoretic closure of

$$\begin{cases} z^2-a^2y\\z^3-a^3x\end{cases},$$

which is a family of schemes in $\mathbb{A}^3 \times \mathbb{A}^1\backslash\{0\}$. It turns out that the corresponding ideal of scheme-theoretic closure in  $\mathbb{A}^3 \times \mathbb{A}^1$ is determined by the ideal $I=(z^2,zx,zy,y^3-x^2)$

How to find out the $I$ in each cases by hand, or at least how to check that these are actually the closures?

The only small trick to check is by Prop.9.7 and Prop.9.8 in III.9, Hartshorne. It is to check that $a$ is not a zero divisor after factoring out $I$. However there are also difficulties to do it by this way.

Comment: If $\operatorname{Spec} B\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ is a morphism of affine schemes, the scheme-theoretic image is just $\operatorname{Spec} A/\ker(A\to B)$. So you're just down to computing the kernel of the ring morphism.

Comment: @KReiser I mean, how to calculate the kernel by hand?